# nil product list in productsRequest:didRecieveResponse:

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, in-app-purchase

I am not getting any product while accessing the product list in code

```
   SKProductsRequest*  _productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]  initWithProductIdentifiers:_productIdentifiers];
    _productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [_productsRequest start];
```

Delegate method

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {

NSLog(@"Loaded list of products...");

NSArray * skProducts = response.products;
for (SKProduct * skProduct in skProducts) {
    NSLog(@"Found product: %@ %@ %0.2f",
          skProduct.productIdentifier,
          skProduct.localizedTitle,
          skProduct.price.floatValue);
    }

}
```

But I am getting a `nil` product list every time. This is the fist update of my app and the previous app does not have in-app purchase option. I have correctly created a provisional profile, certificate and test user.

Edit : I have Created product in itunesconnect but apple review team returned the product with error message **We have returned your IAP product/s to you as the required binary was not submitted. When you are ready to submit the binary, please resubmit the IAPs with the binary. **
Do i need to upload binary and then only i will get product list.? if is it then how to verify the purchase ..? Please help me out .

Comment: Did you create the product in iTunes Connect?

Comment: And what is `_productIdentifiers`? It should be a `NSSet` containing identifiers.

Comment: @ Desdenova Yes ..i have created product in iTunes Connect, but apple haven't approved and return by saying **We have returned your IAP product/s to you as the required binary was not submitted. When you are ready to submit the binary, please resubmit the IAPs with the binary.**  Yes .. _productIdentifiers is NSSet containing product identifiers .

Comment: Please fill the tax and bak info in your apple account.

Comment: You shouldn't be submitting the products for approval until you have tested them so they shouldn't be rejected. That you did suggests you created them and then submitted a version of your app without IAP code in it? Check the `invalidProductIdentifiers` in the response and update your products in iTunesConnect.

Comment: @Wain how to test product with out submitting to itunesconnect ? i mean how to get product list?

Comment: You add them to iTunesConnect, but they don't get reviewed by Apple until you submit the app. As soon as you create them you can query for them (even before you have submitted all of the details required to submit them with the app update)

Answer (score 0):

When you create and add products to iTunesConnect they don't get reviewed by Apple until you submit the app that they are linked to. As soon as you create them you can query for them (even before you have submitted all of the details required to submit them with the app update), but you must test and add IAP before you submit the next version after you create them.

You should generally log the contents of `invalidProductIdentifiers` so that during development you can quickly see simple typo / miss configuration issues.